# Sort out result from sql query

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I use a query to return products & companies from a table (a company can produce 2-3-n type of products)

I'm looking for a way to change the result like this

```
| X | A |
| X | B |
| Y | A | 
| Z | B |
| Z | C |
| Z | D |
```

(where X,Y,Z are companies & A,B,C,D are products)

into something like this

```
| X | A | B |   | 
| Y | A |   |   | 
| Z | B | C | D |
```

Comment: You should look at the `PIVOT` statement...

Comment: what kinda RDBMS Server are you dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

This query will return each company's products in an array:

```
SELECT COMPANY, ARRAY_AGG(PRODUCT) FROM PRODUCTS GROUP BY COMPANY
```

You cannot turn the array into a variable number of columns. But you can get a fixed number of columns by wrapping the SELECT:

```
  SELECT COMPANY, AAA[1], AAA[2], AAA[3], AAA[4] FROM 
   (SELECT COMPANY, AA || ARRAY['', '', ''] AAA FROM
     (SELECT COMPANY, ARRAY_AGG(PRODUCT) AA FROM PRODUCTS GROUP BY COMPANY))
```

The aggregate array has between (1, n) elements, therefore you need to add some empty elements to the end if you want to return a number of elements.